# Which version of the docker-compose file is compose using?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Which version of the file specification is compose using in the case?

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  db:
    image: docker.feedzai.com/hub-proxy/library/postgres:11
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  app:
  image: docker.feedzai.com/hub-proxy/library/postgres:11
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "app_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) , `condition` is no longer supported in docker-compose file version 3. But this configuration works and if I run docker-compose config I still see the version 3.0 there.

So, how can I know which version compose is choosing to interpret this file?

---

How I reproduce this issue

```
# Got a docker with ubuntu jammmy
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash ubuntu:jammy-20220531
>

#Install docker-compose inside the container (v. 1.29.2)
> apt-get update && apt-get install docker-compose
> docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown

# copy the above file to the container (from another terminal)
docker cp docker-compose.yml <container id>:

# run docker-compose config to validate the configuration file
> docker-compose config
services:
  app:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      test:
      - CMD-SHELL
      - app_isready
      timeout: 5s
    image: docker.feedzai.com/hub-proxy/library/postgres:11
  db:
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      test:
      - CMD-SHELL
      - pg_isready
      timeout: 5s
    image: docker.feedzai.com/hub-proxy/library/postgres:11
version: '3.0'
```

Comment: Are you using --compatibility mode? Thats the only way this can be explained. Docker is translating your condition tag as documented here - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/ - check the compatibility mode section.

Comment: I don't think I am, unless it's the default in Ubuntu. I edited the question to show how I reproduce this. Do you see any problems in my example? (I also added an image to the app service)

Comment: This appear to be documented in the current specification (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-1).

Comment: Yes. I didn't meant it was an error. I just want to know which version it is using. Makes sense, right? Otherwise I don't know which reference to check.